# Detect HP ML370 G5 Bad disk in RAID0

Tags: raid, hp, hp-proliant, hp-smart-array, fault-tolerance

I have one HP ML370 G5 server. Which has four 146GB SAS disks and two 300GB SAS disks that are configured as RAID 0.
I have encountered a problem with one of my disks. The windows server event viewer shows the error below:

> Logical drive 2 configured on array controller P400 located in server
>   slot 1 returned a fatal error during a read/write request from/to the
>   volume. Logical block address 6331648, block count 256 and command 32
>   were taken from the failed logical I/O request. Array controller P400
>   located in server slot 1 is also reporting that the last physical
>   drive to report a fatal error condition (associated with this logical
>   request), is located on bus 0 and ID 1.

**How can I determine whether all of my disks work well or not? and check for bad blocks on my disks!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install the HP Smart Array Configuration Utility on you Windows Server and determine on wich disc the error occurred. You can also restart your System and open the Smart Array Configuration Utility from startup to determine wich disc works wrong.

The Configuration Utility must be install on windows and you doesn't need a restart. You can download it from:

[HP Support site](http://h20566.www2.hp.com/portal/site/hpsc/template.PAGE/public/psi/swdDetails/?sp4ts.oid=1157687&spf_p.tpst=swdMain&spf_p.prp_swdMain=wsrp-navigationalState=swItem%253DMTX_669f83062c7b492083c2aa7125&javax.portlet.begCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken&javax.portlet.endCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken)

**Update**
When you opened HP ACU you can go to "show Systemstatus" or change the view to "physical View" to access the status of each drive. But you can do the same with insight diagnostic, too.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have used HP ACU. but the report is somehow obscure. I used hp insight diagnostics and the result is as below:

Comment: Hard Drive 2, 300.0 GB, 10k RPM, SAS, HP EG0300FAWHV Failed
Error: F149: The controller has reported a S.M.A.R.T. error on this drive.

Comment: If you have S.M.A.R.T. Errors on this drive you should change the Drive.

Comment: If these disks are in RAID 0 and there's data that you care about, you should NOT replace the drive without copying/moving/backing-up your data.

Comment: @ kockiren: THe HP ACU says all disks are ok. But HP Diagnosis is raising the error above

Comment: You can try to copy (dd) the drive to the new one

Comment: You can do a drive physical test with knoppicillin for example, do a dd copy of this drive at first and then do a physical fitness test but not beyond the raid controller.

Comment: If the ACU doesn't show errors you can try to copy your data to another system and change the RAID Level away from RAID 0

Answer (score 2):

If these disks are in two logical drives of RAID 0, you may not have any recourse beyond copying your data off the system.

**You won't be able to *just* replace the failing disk without incurring data loss.**

Are you *sure* that you're using RAID 0?